# C# StreamWriter and StreamReader memory managment problem, why won't memory used deallocate?

Tags: c#, memory-management, streamreader, memorystream, streamwriter

So I'm using a StreamReader that uses a MemoryStream to write to a StreamWriter and inside of this application but the memory usage increases by 300mb (From one of the larger inputs) and does not deallocate after Im done using it:

```
StreamWriter log = new StreamWriter("tempFile.txt");
log.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
log.Close();

reader.DiscardBufferedData();
reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
memoryStream.Dispose();
log.Dispose();
GC.Collect();
```

Before this and right after I get the RAM usage and before it is 300 mb less than after but I don't know why. I have done everything I can think of to release that memory considering that the only thing going on here is the data from the reader is being placed in the text file I don't see why any large amount of memory would even need to be used temporarily. Is there something I am missing?... Thanks.

Comment: I recommend running a performance profiler on your application.  You may find that the performance issues you're encountering actually don't have anything to do with the reported memory footprint.  Depending on how much data you're writing to disk, it's likely that the bigger culprit impacting other processes is contention over disk I/O resources.  Memory really shouldn't be a performance concern (as far as impact on other processes) until you're actually overflowing physical RAM and causing significant disk paging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking at the RAM used by the process itself? I wouldn't expect that to go down. The process will hang on to that memory and reuse it for further allocations. It doesn't hand it back to the operating system. That's just the way .NET tends to work.

You *can* potentially get it to throw away the memory with some CLR API call - but usually I wouldn't.

This doesn't mean the memory has really leaked - it's still usable by the same process. For example, if you performed the same action again it probably wouldn't need to increase the size of the heap - you'd see the memory usage stay flat at the process level. Use the CLR perfmon graphs to see the memory used within the managed heap to see if there's a *genuine* leak.

(There are also various different measure of how much memory an application is actually using. Which one is interesting depends on what you're trying to do.)

EDIT: If your code snippet is genuinely indicative of the code you're using, then there's a much simpler alternative: stream the data.

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("tempFile.txt"))
{
    CopyText(reader, writer);
}

static void CopyText(TextReader reader, TextWriter writer)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[8192];
    int charsRead;
    while ((charsRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, charsRead);
    }
}
```

Note that unless you're actually changing the encoding, you could do this without using a `TextWriter`/`TextReader` pair to start with.

That way you won't need to have the whole string in memory *as well as its binary representation* (in the `MemoryStream`). You'll still have the binary representation of course - do you *have* to write everything into the `MemoryStream` to start with?

Comment: I am using System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter()s NextValue() to get available memory, it seems as though the RAM usage is getting dangerously high. This application would be a process running in the background so it is important that it does not hog system resources like it currently is.

Comment: @Sam can you try running another application that uses a lot of memory and see if adding some memory pressure causes usage to go down? Because it's only hogging resources if it prevents other apps from getting memory they need.

Comment: I see, I will try that however during the runtime, when using other applications there is a noticeable slowdown when even opening the windows start menu.

Comment: @Sam F: I've added some code which could significantly slim down the amount of memory required, by streaming the data out instead of reading it all into a big string.

Comment: I'm not sure about having to write it into a MemoryStream, it was an example from a SharpSVN tutorial, I will definately check to see if the function is overloaded for other classes. Thanks for the advice! The 8192, is that the size of a string? I know that systems like sizes that are powers of 2 but just wondering why that one specifically. Thanks again.

Comment: System.IO.Stream is the function argument type which is where it puts the data.

Comment: @Sam: Well if you want to write the data out to a file, just pass it a file stream... The 8192 is just a reasonable buffer size. It will keep reading up to 8K characters of data at a time, writing each chunk out as it goes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Jon posted, the way the .NET runtime behaves acutally gives you some important *benefits* - keeping the memory allocated for the process is a good thing unless the system is low on memory (in which case, the runtime would probably release it).

For example, if you often need to allocate lot of memory (as in the method you posted here), then it is more efficient if the process already has the memory allocated (even though it isn't used to store any .NET objects). When you runt he method next time, the allocation will be much faster!

Anyway, a few things you could do are:

- You may try running another memory intensive application to see whether the runtime releases the memory when the system needs it
- You can use some .NET profiler to see whether there are any live objects that you would expect to be collected after running the method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll help, but try some `using` scoping:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(somestream))
using (StreamWriter log = new StreamWriter("tempFile.txt"))
{
    log.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the segment mentioned above, all of `log`, `reader`, and `memoryStream` are still in scope and so can't be garbage collected. I don't know what the implmentation of `Dispose` on those objects is, but it's entirely likely that they're still holding much of the data in memory even after `Dispose` is called (since `Dispose` typically only closes filehandles, unmanaged memory, and such, and doesn't necessarily delete internal buffers). If you want this to work as expected, you have to let all of the referenced objects go out of scope and become unreferenced.

Really, though, you shouldn't worry about this unless memory usage is causing you explicit pain.

Comment: It seems that at certain times throughout the programs runtime, the OS starts to creep and just opening windows and moving them around become a slow and unresponsive task.

Comment: The values can be garbage collected straight after the final read, when you're not running in the debugger. You can even write to the variable later, and that doesn't stop it from being GC'd earlier.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: So the entire app is using about 500 mb more RAM than I would expect, is this 500 mb natural for .NET to hold on to? I would think there is a limit to the amount of buffer memory it keeps around.

Comment: That suggests you've needed that much memory at some point. I wouldn't particularly expect it to give that memory back.